# Facebook Apps Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I have noticed that this new horizontal scroll bar at the bottom which I am unable to remove. I have attached an image in which i have also clearly marked the scroll bar which i am talking about. I know there is canvas setting in app settings but that is for the scroll bars above this one. When i scroll the marked scroll bar to the right the chat & notifications also get scrolled something which didn't use to happen before.

[image: Facebook Application with Scrollbar]

Comment: Tried it on Mozilla & IE too. It appears to be Chrome only issue

Comment: As far as I can see it is happening on all Safari-based browsers.

Comment: Happening on Firefox 26.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported Facebook API bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182748101891780

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the "fb-like" attribute data-width="100px" (or whatever width you like) and it solves this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem to be this element from FB ui, in the right column:

```
<div style="width:246px; height:69px; " class="_56vv _56vw" id="u_0_j">
```

It's the Recommended Games block, which has a carousel inside it. It should have a overflow:hidden in CSS. Tried to access it from my app via javascript, but FB blocked it.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I used since this issue was making me crazier.

I use Stylish to customize Facebook, and I have a style installed that blocks all the useless crap on that site, i.e. friend recommendations, ads, unused navigation items on the left, etc.

All I did was find the DIV that holds the entire right sidebar and disabled it. This effectively got rid of the scrollbar and centers the main content within the middle DIV.

Here's the line I added to Stylish:

```
#rightCol {display:none;}
```

And just for your reference, here's the whole list I use for Facebook:

```
.rightColumnWrapper {display:none;}
#navHome{display:none;}
#pagelet_ego_pane {display:none;}
#pagelet_friend_list_suggestions {display:none;}
#appsNav {display:none;}
#pagelet_ticker {display:none;}
#fbSidebarGripper {display:none;}
#pagelet_welcome {display:none;}
#rightCol {display:none;}
.groupMemberSuggestionsList{display:none;}
.groupRecommendationsList{display:none;}
```

Hope this helps if you haven't already found a solution.